# How to find r home and r user path commands in Rstudio?

Tags: r

I would like to find the path `R_HOME` and `R_USER` in order to add the to environment variables.

Is the any command to make it from R studio?

Comment: Check out `?Sys.getenv` and `?Sys.setenv`

Comment: @JorisChau thank you. I don't try to find from R the environmental variables but where the paths are to add them to environmental variables